# Scheduling app in ionic which triggers functions after specified time

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, scheduled-tasks

I'm a newbie to Ionic app development and have a requirement for which I've mined the internet but in vain.

My requirement is as below:

The user can select a Time Period i.e say 3hrs from now, after this time period, a trigger will run within the app and will perform a certain function depending what the user has selected (like play music, send sms or email). I have my individual modules of code ready for playing music, sending sms or email.

I only need to know how to trigger those events in ionic.

The important part is that the trigger should work even when **the app is closed**, **screen is locked** and **should also survive a reboot**.

I've  tried the following, http://www.gajotres.net/how-to-use-local-notifications-with-ionic-framework/ , 
https://github.com/wnyc/cordova-plugin-wakeuptimer , 
https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-real-time-scheduling-app-using-angularjs-and-firebase but could not meet my requirements and in Vain.

Please help me and guide me through this.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: For such a task you have to write your own native plugin. It is not possible to do this with Cordova out of the box.

Comment: This is not something that the native platforms allow, let alone Cordova, let alone Ionic. Maybe on Android, but you'd have better luck reading the cordova docs than the Ionic docs. Ionic is only a design framework that sits ontop of Cordova.

Comment: @Joerg thanks for your advice,I'll try that option.

Comment: @Quill I read through the cordova pluggin documentation but could'nt find any. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Thats not possible with ionic, as hack u can use [local notification](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications) and schedule notification as per ur requirement, on tap u can call any other action.